# Change country in Exact API

Tags: exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

i am using Exact API with this code https://github.com/picqer/exact-php-client using de example.php file with my RedirectURL, ClientId and ClientSecret the problem is it always responds with "Client not found" error message.

This is the answer of support department of exact:

"Please change the .NL part to .ES. If you have registered an app in the Spanish app center, make sure your oauth calls are also aimed at Exact Online .ES."

My question is: how can i change this .NL part? i´ve search in all the code with no results.

Answer (score 1):

Change the base URL, [as documented](https://github.com/picqer/exact-php-client):

```
$connection->setBaseUrl('https://start.exactonline.es');
```